# how to get PLY to ignore text exists in between the open and close tags?

Tags: yacc, ply

In the case of php only code enclosed  get parsed, ignore other characters before or after it.

Assume we have the following:

```
LEX
t_OPEN= r'\<\?php'
t_CLOSE = r'\?\>'


YACC
'''program : OPEN statements CLOSE'''
```

if the input looks like below, it will generate an error

```
randomstring <?php echo 1 ?>
```

I tried tokens use regex to capture not enclosed text, did not work. is there any way to do this?

```
def t_RANDOM(t) :
    r'(.*)\<\?'
    pass
```

Comment: Please include a complete (but minimal) example which we can run to see the error.